# Разложить дробь на сумму дробей

Tags: c, алгоритм

Помогите с решением задачи.
Как должен выглядеть алгоритм? Разложить дробь p/q на сумму дробей вида 1/n. Например, 3/7=1/3+1/11+1/231. Все решается через цикл, только какие параметры подбора должны быть?
Если кому не сложно, помогите. Заранее спасибо. Язык Си.

Comment: Я, конечно, не математик, но разве 3/7 не тоже, что и (1/7+1/7+1/7)?

Comment: К сожалению, как оказывается, нет. Это египетские дроби вроде. Вопрос, что с алгоритмом?

Comment: @OverLoader, так вы бы написали, что дроби должны быть разные. Имхо, алгоритм разложения лучше на [математике](http://math.hashcode.ru/) спросить, а с проблемами с реализацией уже сюда.

Comment: Ну раз вы знаете название, то беглый взгляд в википедию по [египетским дробям](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Египетские_дроби) и алгоритм Фибоначчи найден, да еще и подробно описан. Берем формулу, в цикл пока второе слагаемое не приобретет единицу в числителе и готово.